# Irssi Config File Hilight Default Values Functionality For Text/Channel

Tags: config, putty, irssi

I have the following in my irssi config:

```
hilights = (
  {
    text = "!starcraftsignal";
    color = "%B";
    actcolor = "%B";
  },
  {
    actcolor = "%G";
    channels = "#glass";
  },
  {
    actcolor = "#Y";
    channels = "#robots";
  },
);
```

I use Putty to SSH and want the channels #robots and #glass to get highlighted in the channel overview strip at the bottom with numbers whenever a message is made in any of the channels I'm not in, and I want the same to happen when someone says !starcraftsignal irregardless of channel.

Currently my config isn't working. Do I need to specify the text field even for hilighting for any/all messages made and if so, what do I specify it to? Also do I need to list all the channels for !starcraftsignal or is the 'default' all channels I'm connected to?